# Android PullToRefresh ptrOverScroll="false" is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, maven, gradle

I added compile 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.3@aar' to my build.gradle.

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    ptr:ptrOverScroll="false"/>
```

I made my xml like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

    mPullRefreshListView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_list);
    mPullRefreshListView
            .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh(
                        PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
                    new ProcessTask().execute();
                }
            });

    items = new String[31];
    for (int index = 0; index <= 30; index++) {
        items[index] = "list " + index;
    }
    mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
}

public class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dddd",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0l;
        }
        return 1l;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();
    }
}
```

pullToRefresh is working perfectly. but overscroll is never removed.

I wasted 6 hours to try to solve this problem.

what's the problem?